# Incrementing via MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looking for a way to increment and decrement by a step of three records in a table and return them.

Say ID '4' is currently active. I want to get the next 3 and the previous 3 records with IDs and category of 3.2.1 and 5.6.7 (via incrementing and decrementing).

So far I have:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, category FROM test");
$stmt->execute();

while ($results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $current = $results['id'];
    $category = $results['category'];
    $next = array(array(
        'slide_no' => $current, 
        'category' => $category
    ));
}

print_r($next);
```

Using this, I am getting back every row in the table.

I'm getting confused how to increment and decrement the records by a step of 3 and make sure that the category will also increment accordingly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a string with the 6 ids that you need.

So if CatID was 4 you would want

$selectIDs = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7";

Then when you perform your SQl you would use
    "SELECT id, category FROM test WHERE id IN (" . $selectIDs ."')";

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to `paginate` the displayed data. You need to use the `MySQL LIMIT clause`.
You'll need to adjust your query, using values generated from your code. See an example below:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, category FROM test LIMIT ?, 3");
#you'll supply the ? parameter depending on your current start index
```

[MySQL Limit clause Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the => and <= operators.

First store the id in a variable:

```
$intId = 4
```

Then add and decrement 3

```
$intAdd = $intId + 3
$intDecr = $intId -3
```

Then setup your sql string

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT id, category FROM test where id =>'.  $intDecr.' and <= '.$intAdd. ');
```